# Accessing structure descendants data

Tags: matrix, structure, entrymodel

I have a structure with 1 main Entry and 3 descendants underneath it but I have trouble accessing the data in matrix fields in the entries. I'm trying to do this all on one page:

```
{% set tabs = entry.descendants %}
     {% for tab in tabs %}
          {{ tab.title }}
     {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

I can get as far as the tab title, and it displays fine. But I want to access the matrix fields in the descendants. Here are the blocks in my field with the handle 'tab'.

[image: Blocks]

So to summarise, I have a structure:

[image: Structure]

and then I want to use all those descendant data all one one page but I'm having trouble accessing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would loop through the Matrix field within each `tab` the same way you’d do it for any other element.

```twig
{% set tabs = entry.descendants %}
{% for tab in tabs %}
    {{ tab.title }}
    {% for block in tab.myMatrixFieldHandle %}
        {% if block.type == 'about' %}
            ...
        {% elseif block.type == 'team' %}
            ...
        {% elseif block.type == 'clients' %}
            ...
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks - my problem was in naming as my matrixFieldHandle was actually called 'tab' - bit of a Herp Derp moment!